# How to call a method from a class in oter class? Cannot read property 'test' JS

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

```
var test = function (){

    this.text="hello word!!! ";
    
    this.hello= function(){
        alert(this.text);
    }
}
```

I have this class... And i wanna use this class in other class for to say hello.
So i do that:

```
class Alert{
    test;

    constructor(){
        console.log("Starting class alert.")
        this.test= new test();
    }

    say (){
        test.hello()
    }
}

main = new Alert();
main.say();
```

And that drop me the mext error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'say' of undefined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>
```

So i don't know how to solve it, if someone know can help...

Comment: Please add the HTML that creates the error as well. Also, `test.hello()` should be `this.test.hello()`

Comment: Also `javascript !== java`

Comment: @adiga Yes I did it and nothing...

Comment: Unless this question includes both java and javascript, please remove the incorrect tag. Java and Javascript are very different languages.

Comment: `this.test` is one of the issues. You have not provided the `HTMLButtonElement` and how you are calling `say` which is mentioned in the error.

Comment: I am assuming  you know which language you are programming in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to use **var**, **let** or **const** to declare variables.

Also if you want to call a method inside of the class use `this` keyword.

```
var test = function (){

this.text="hello word!!! ";

this.hello= function(){
    alert(this.text);
}
}

class Alert{
    test;

    constructor(){
        console.log("Starting class alert.")
        this.test= new test();
    }

    say (){
        this.test.hello()
    }
}

var main = new Alert();
main.say();
```

```js
var test = function (){

  this.text="hello word!!! ";

  this.hello= function(){
      alert(this.text);
  }
}

class Alert{
    test;

    constructor(){
        console.log("Starting class alert.")
        this.test= new test();
    }

    say (){
        this.test.hello()
    }
}

var main = new Alert();
main.say();
```

Comment: I did it and nothing